# Dynamic aspx page or load from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm asked to build a simple web site. Every page of this site is mainly text. I want them to be able to change all the text dynamicly. 
What is a better way:

1) To store all the text in database.

2) On text change replace existing aspx file with new one with changed text.

I would prefer a way where the changed pages will load faster on client side

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: This is not a constructive question I'm afraid.. How are we supposed to solve this dilemma for you? This is not a discussion, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: You should look into a CMS, maybe something like http://www.orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 2):

Given these requirements, your best solution is a CMS (content management system).

There are plenty of options for asp.net, like Umbraco, DotNetNuke etc.

Doing this by storing all the text in the database will be just like implementing a CMS. The second option is really really old school. You may as well put static html pages on the server in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should change text in the controller. Don't replace pages.

Comment: Assuming he's using MVC.

Comment: so i will need to store the changed text in database for this solution. Is't it faster to load just aspx page with already changed data?